# Does Grumble, Worldshaker return creatures in a random order?

Tags: hearthstone

I thought Grumble, Worldshaker would return minions left -> right.

However if my hand is full, I've observed both:

- The right most creature on the board were put into my hand, the others destroyed.
- I've dropped 1 creature on the left, then world shaker on the left. And had the 2 middle totems get returned, other cards destroyed.

Is it completely random which creatures survive into my hand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not a random order. The minions/totems are returned based on which was played first, second, third etc.

For example, you have 9 cards in hand and you have played cards A, B, C, and D on the board. You play Grumble. A and B are returned to your hand. C and D are considered killed. As a side note, because C and D are considered kill on the board state, if they have a deathrattle effect, they will trigger.

Answer (score 4):

Actions are processed based on the order of play.  Thus, your minions are returned to your hand based on the order in which they were originally played.